# How to put Processing in HTML page?

Tags: processing

Is there a way to put Processing in an HTML page? Say I have a .pde file, and I want it to be on my HTML web page, how could I do that? (Processing is a kind of a graphics language.)

Comment: what is a "Processing file"?

Comment: @MitchWheat According to http://processing.org/reference/environment/, "The PDE file extension is an acronym for the Processing Development Environment."

Comment: @Chris Culter: how did you infer that from the question?

Comment: @MitchWheat Well, I happen to have used Processing before. Anyway, the question is tagged [tag:processing], and it refers to .pde files, so I was pretty sure of the context.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/processing%20on%20the%20web/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to export your pde file into a HTML page with [Processing](https://processing.org/download/?processing)'s [JavaScript mode](http://wiki.processing.org/w/JavaScript#About_JavaScript_mode). A `web-export` folder will be created and containing everything you need for deployment (`index.html`, `processing.js`, and other resource files...).

You may also consider to take this [Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/course/digitalmedia) which gives you an overview of what Processing can do. I've finished this and it's fun and useful!

Comment: This _should_ work, but it doesn't. I opened up index.html, and the sketch wouldn't show.

Comment: you need a running server to host your project; in processing, simply select javascript mode and *start server*

Answer (score 4):

Would [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org) work for you?

Comment: Yes, Processing.js would be fine.

Comment: Wait, don't leave yet. I downloaded Processing.js, and I opened the example HTML file, and the examples didn't work!

Comment: @Ptr13 Oh, sorry, I don't think I can help you with that. I've only ever used the "native" Java client, myself.

Comment: Darn. Do you know of somewhere that I could find the answer?

Comment: @Ptr13 Hmm, there's a [tag:processing.js] tag with some past answers on various error messages. Other than that, I'm not sure. There's http://processingjs.org/community/, but I've never been there, so I can't recommend it one way or the other.

Comment: You can use the Processing.js addon right from the PDE in version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to put Processing code directly in your web page
>   Using the data-processing-sources attribute on the canvas, and having Processing.js load an external file is the preferred and recommended way to include scripts in a web page. However, it is also possible to write in-line Processing code.

Processing code example ( worked for me ) ( easiest way I guess ) :

```
<script src="processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>      
<script type="application/processing" data-processing-target="pjs">
      void setup() {
        size(200, 200);
       background(100);
        stroke(255);
        ellipse(50, 50, 25, 25);
        println('hello web!');
      }
     </script>
     <canvas id="pjs"> </canvas>
```